# In PowerPoint VBA, how to use `TextRange.Runs.Font.Bold` to insert `<b>` and `<\b>` tags around the returned text range?

Tags: vba, fonts, microsoft-powerpoint

I'm using VBA in Powerpoint to find styles in the text and then wrap that text with HTML markdown tags. Below is the code I'm trying to use to find **bold text** and then wrap it in `<b>bold text</b>`.

Unfortunately, the code seems to return boolean, not a textrange.

What am I doing wrong?

```
With oSh.TextFrame.TextRange
For x = 1 To .Paragraphs.Count
    With .Paragraphs(x)
        Debug.Print "Paragraph: " & x
        For y = 1 To .Runs.Count
            If .Runs(y).Font.Bold Then
                .Runs(y).Font.Bold = "<b>" & .Runs(y).Font.Bold & "</b>"
            End If
        Next
    End With
Next
End With
```

Comment: What is your exact problem? What happens wrongly? Do you get error message (what, at which line)? Do you get wrong output?

Comment: `.Font.Bold` is a boolean value, you need to use the value of the text itself. What you have done is say "if isbold = true then set isbold = text & true & text" which makes no sense and may evaluate to false or true or simply throw an error, depending on the language.

Comment: I am getting an error... can't recreate right now... as now I'm on a mac... it is a generic error while compiling... something about objects...

Comment: as per the Documentation... `.Runs` is supposed to return a textrange not a boolean... what i need to figure out is "where does bold, italic, underline, or colored substring start... and where does it end? " Then wrap that in it's corresponding markdown/HTML

Comment: Could someone with The Power please take this off hold?  The question about the code itself might be improved, but the intent is perfectly clear and the question's been answered to the OP's satisfaction (and OP has added a comment that enabled an improved answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like so ... this'll work with the currently selected shape; assign whatever you like to oSh, so long as it has text:

```
Sub EmboldenAndItalicize()

Dim oSh As Shape
Dim x As Long

Set oSh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)

With oSh.TextFrame.TextRange
For x = 1 To .Runs.Count
    If .Runs(x).Font.Bold Then
        .Runs(x).Text = "<b>" & .Runs(x).Text & "</b>"
    End If
Next
For x = 1 To .Runs.Count
    If .Runs(x).Font.Italic Then
        .Runs(x).Text = "<i>" & .Runs(x).Text & "</i>"
    End If
Next

End With

End Sub
```

A shape's TextRange has a Runs collection; if there's no formatting change within the text, the Runs collection will have only one member; otherwise, there's a new Runs member for each formatting change.

Comment: Awesome... this basically implies that if the same text block is bold and italics ... we should check for it separately... lest we have the same text repeated under different tags...

Comment: Exactly so ... good point.  See edited version.  I've checked this with bold only, italic only, bold + italic and some odd overlapping combinations and so far it works on all.